# Best option to develop an Android app able to sync data between users

Tags: android, synchronization, cloud

I am developing an Android application to manage projects and I would like to be able to sync information between different users. I think a good option would be to be able to use the Google account to sync data similar to how notes are shared in Google Keep (different users participate in editing a note). How could I achieve this in my app, is there a better option than using the Google account? I'm just starting out in Android app development and any advice is welcome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.